# How to fix "cropping" shapes in OpenGL (lwjgl)?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, opengl-compat

I am doing a project on OpenGL 3D. I have several figures, and when I rotate the camera (scene), the figures seem to go beyond it (or beyond Viewport)

Normal condition:

[image: Normal condition]

Cropped figure:

[image: Cropped figure]

How can I increase the viewing area? Or what can be done in this situation?

Now I am trying:

```
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
        glfwPollEvents();
        glPushMatrix();
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
```

But it does not bring results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the object is clipped by the near plane of then orthographic projection. Change the near plane to solve the issue.
The orthographic projection matrix is set by [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml).

By default the projection matrix is the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix). That is the same as you would do

```java
GL11.glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1);
```

Increase the distance to the near and far plane to solve the issue. e.g:

```java
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, 10, -10);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

I try:

```GL11.glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -2, 1);```

```GL11.glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -2, -2);```

```GL11.glOrtho(-1, -1, -1, -1, -2, -2);```

```GL11.glOrtho(-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2);```

But the problem still remains

Comment: @DmitryTriangle Do you set or overwrite the  projection matrix (`GL_PROJECTION`) somewhere else?

Comment: ```GL11.glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -10, 10);``` work for me, but it turned the scene 180 degrees

Comment: @DmitryTriangle Swap -10 and 10.